# Does Windows Firewall block ICMPv6 by default?

Tags: networking, ipv6, windows-firewall

After a long struggle trying to establish IPv6 connectivity with Windows box (and failing) I noticed that Windows Firewall blocks a lot of ICMPv6 packets. Closest predefined rule I could find does allow ICMPv6, but only for `Local network` connections, which is too limited compared to recommendations from [rfc4890](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4890.txt) dated "May 2007" (which is way before Windows 7 was released).

Of course I did expand that rule to `Any` as well as tried adding separate ICMPv6 rule — both successful independently. It does a little difference for usual network activity, but gives a huge benefit for tunnelled connections (IPv6 tunnelled over IPv4 for P2P IPv6 direct connections for instance), which hardly operate otherwise.

Am I missing something here or getting it wrong?

If that is "by design", what is the point in limiting this rule to `Local network` by default contrary to recommendations?

Comment: Even if this question has no answer it might serve a reference for anyone, encountering such a behaviour of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to explicitly create a new custom inbound rule that passes ICMPv6 for the needed needed interface and network type. It's rather easy to do:

[Passing ICMPv6 on Windows Defender Firewall](https://noobient.com/post/176558040901/passing-icmpv6-on-windows-defender-firewall)

Comment: Unfortunately, you seem to just rephrase the quote from the question itself: `Of course I did expand that rule to Any as well as tried adding separate ICMPv6 rule — both successful independently.` Given that this information is already present in question, what additional knowledge does your answer provide?

Comment: Also, this is an example of why link-only answers are discouraged. The link is offline.

Comment: Because I'm in the middle of migrating the site.

Comment: @PF4Public The additional rule is the affirmation that the custom rule is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unrelated, but I have noticed that if the network is set to "Public" the Router sollications go away after aquiring an address via SLAAC.

When I set the firewall profile to "Private" it immediately springs to life and starts working again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).